# what is marketingcloudops.com?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, sftp

With the SFTP changes coming soon, I realized that with our customers some of them have the ftp as  S1: ftp://ftp1.exacttarget.com and others as marketingcloudops.com

I was looking at the Marketing Cloud SFTP Guide and I found this note

> NOTE All new and existing FTP integrations continue to work when using the legacy structure. However, we recommend using the new Marketing Cloud marketingcloudops.com URL for improved performance.

but nothing else.

My question is what is the difference between them? Is it worth upgrading? What does the upgrade involves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new tenant specific URLs, both for FTP and API integrations, are introduced for performance reasons:

> Because subdomains are unique and assigned to each tenant, we can
>   better optimize our customers’ experience. The new tenant-specific
>   Marketing Cloud endpoint structure provides an improved API
>   performance and a faster Marketing Cloud experience.

I will recommend upgrading to the new endpoints when convenient, however I don’t foresee the performance improvement will be significantly measurable from your side.

Read more about tenant specific subdomains [here.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2018_platform_tenant_specific_subdomains.htm&type=5)